# Is there any other way to model this archway?

Tags: mesh, topology

I want to make a hole to a plane in this way but it's taking so much time. I deleted faces and added spin to a vertex and joined the vertices I want to make it even easier is there any other way to make this
[image]

Comment: "*is there any other way to do this?*" Please use a descriptive title that sumarizes the specific content of the question

Comment: how to make the curve on the top,easily

Comment: use subdivision modifier? Round stuff is usually achived by using subdiv, bevel or boolean. Spin is also a good and fast option if you dont do it for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for *Proportional editing*.

Set it to *Sphere* faloff and adjust *size* to your liking.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU IM SEARCHING FOR THIS TYPE