# How to inset odd shape

Tags: modeling, geometry

**Disclaimer**: Fairly new to 3D modeling; done some simple things, trying to model stuff around me.

I am trying to model a space where I live (Gibraltar in case you care) that is essentially a repetition of the sections pictured below. It looks like the arch could be done as an inset into a larger face, but how to I set up to inset an odd shape like that? Is this even the best approach or would I be better off building it up from smaller chunks?

[image: Wellington Front, Gibraltar]

Comment: Hello :). This answer could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174872/

Comment: @JachymMichal Oh that is cool!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should begin with the circle arc, then extrude up, down and inwards. When you'll have finished, use a texture to create the stones.

[image]

Comment: Mad props for modeling an entire archway complete with doors and windows :).

Comment: thanks mate!  ;)

Comment: @moonboots that is fantastic! Thanks, I am learning a lot more than I asked for.

Answer (score 2):

this is just about moving the verteces on the right place. I started from the plane, align verteces, extruded, deleted the bottom and use subdivide modifier to make it round. To keep the shape of the corners I use bevel and edge crease (the purple edges, Shift+E) You can as well support the edges by adding more. When the architecture is repetitive, it is a good way to model just part and then duplicate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

subdivide your surface (so you have more points). align inside vertices to have the shape and then after selecting planes you want to make a hole with use extrude but do it to the inside ;]
You could do bollen math but that destroys the mesh

Comment: Yeah I did try the Boolean modifier but it looked horrible.